# How can i return required columns from database through eloquent model in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to return required columns from my database through an eloquent model with relation.

```
public function Page()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Page', 'subcategory_id');     
}
```

And this is how I return data in my controller

```
$subcategoryContent = SubCategory::where('slug',$subcategory)->with('Page')->get();
```

All I want is to return is the page name and slug according to it's subcategory id by the relation.
The relations works fine but  I want the subcategory details and the names of the pages that belongs to the subcategory.
Thank You!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$subcategoryContent = SubCategory::where('slug',$subcategory)->first()->Page()->pluck('title','id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment you need to add a select statement:

In your `->with()` query builder you need to use the select statement with a `:`:

```
$subcategoryContent = SubCategory::where('slug',$subcategory)->with('Page:id,title')->get();
```

Answer (score -1):

what result you get from this? and what result you want from this??

usually i just get the subCategory in controller..

```
$subCategorys = SubCategory::where('slug',$subcategory)->get();
```

then i write this in view

**edit in view based your answer..**

```
@foreach($subCategorys as $sub)
{{ $sub->name}}

     @foreach($sub->Page as $page)
        {{$page->title}}
        {{$page->id}}
     @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: right now i'm getting the subcategory and the pages that belongs to the subcategory.
but its returning all the data of **Pages** table which belongs to the **subcategory** and i wanted only the title and id.

Comment: i think about two solution but havent try it yet..
first use pluck, second use db::raw than select everything you need..